# Stop chewing! What is it called when someone doesn't like the sound of other people eating?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests, food, phobias

My brother hates the sound of eating, chewing, slurping, swallowing etc.

I am looking for either:

- The name of the condition or
- A word to describe the type of person who behaves like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*What is it called when someone doesn't like the sound of other people eating?*

A condition in which a person is **hypersensitive to eating noises** can be called **misophonia**:

> *Hate the Sound of People Chewing? You Might Have Misophonia*
>
> *Misophonia* — a term coined by researchers studying ear ringing in the early 2000s — means “hatred of sound,” but it generally refers to **a hatred of specifically human sounds**. These are often **related to eating** (like lip smacking or chewing) or related to repetitive sounds like breathing or pen-clicking.

([mentalfloss.com](http://mentalfloss.com/article/67614/hate-sound-people-chewing-you-might-have-misophonia))

Answer (score 0):

Polite people don't usually make noises when they eat or drink.  They don't slurp, guzzle or belch at table.  At least they try not to and they tend to disapprove of those who do.  For this reason, I think the phrase you are looking for is **"people of a polite mindset"**.

Answer (score 0):

You could say that this person has *"Bad table manners"*

A person who has bad table manners could be called *inconsiderate*, *impolite*, *rude*, *uncouth* among many others.